# Error Cloning a GitHub repository to SAP Web IDE "Path name is invalid"

Tags: git, github, repository, sap-web-ide

I'm trying to clone a git repository to the SAP Web IDE but when I do it either clones the whole repository, but the link for version control fails. Or it doesn't clone anything. Either way here is the error I get

```
Unhandled Error: Path name is invalid: >/SAP_SARAH_ML_Project/Shelf UI<
```

The repository I'm trying to clone is here:
https://github.com/CTOverton/SAP_SARAH_ML_Project.git

*Note: I don't believe it's the space in the folder name becuase there is another directory "Image Crop" that has a space and that doesn't throw and error and that one is first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aperently the Web IDE doesn’t like spaces in the file names. I didn’t think this was he error but after testing it it was.

Solution:
Remove spaces in folder and file names